# Python, batch converting degrees minutes seconds to decimal degrees in a .csv with thousands of records

Tags: python, excel, csv

I am a beginner Python user and I am having troubles understanding some things. I want to convert 2 whole columns (lat, long) in a .csv file from degrees minutes seconds (dms) to decimal degrees (dd) (ie. 46°57'01"N  to 46.950278). I'm probably doing this the long way around, but I don't know any better. So far I have renamed the headings in my .csv to be readable in ArcGIS. Then I used Excel to replace the °, ', and "N with spaces and then put them in a new .csv file with their respective ID number (Acc_num)...wanted to use Python, but couldn't figure it out for the life of me. Then I replaced the spaces with commas to be able to convert each section coordinate. I also made a def to convert dms to dd, dm to dd and d to dd...did this because some of my coordinates are only degrees and some are only degrees minutes. Here is an overview of my .csv file current format:

```
Acc_num    lat      long
881138    80,24     87,38
882273    68,40     141
889843    56,55,28  91,49,02
787004    48        91,58
```

I don't know how to apply my defs to the .csv file to do the final conversion to dd. I need to keep the list in the same order because I want to insert these columns back into the original, more detailed .csv.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import csv
from itertools import izip
filename = r'C:\workspace\code\hl.csv'
filename_comma = r'C:\workspace\code\hundlich4.csv'
def dms_dd(degrees, minutes, seconds):
    decimal = 0.0
    if (degrees >= 0):
        decimal = degrees + float(minutes)/60 + float(seconds)/3600
    else:
        decimal = degrees - float(minutes)/60 - float(seconds)/3600
    return decimal
def dm_dd(degrees, minutes):
    decimal = 0.0
    if (degrees >= 0):
        decimal = degrees + float(minutes)/60
    else:
        decimal = degrees - float(minutes)/60
    return decimal
def d_dd(degrees):
    decimal = 0.0
    if (degrees >= 0):
        decimal = degrees
    else:
        decimal = degrees
    return decimal
accession = []
latitudes = []
longitudes = []
f = open(filename)
for line in f:
    cells = line.split(',')
    accession.append((cells[0]))   
    latitudes.append((cells[1]))
    latitudes = [w.replace(' ', ',') for w in latitudes]
    longitudes.append((cells[2]))
    longitudes = [w.replace(' ', ',') for w in longitudes]
    longitudes = [w.replace('\n', '') for w in longitudes]
#puts commas where spaces are for the coordinates
f.close()

with open('C:\workspace\code\hundlich4.csv', 'wb') as fn:
    writer = csv.writer(fn)
    writer.writerows(izip(accession, latitudes, longitudes))
#writes columns with commas to a new csv called hundlich4.csv
```

And now I've been working on this, and I know it is wrong, but I have no idea what to do for the conversion to get my defs applied.

```
accession2 = []
latitudes2 = []
longitudes2 = []

ff = open(filename)
for line in ff:
    cells = line.split(',')
    accession2.append((cells[0]))   
    latitudes2.append((cells[1]))
        for val in latitudes2:
            dms_dd(val)
    longitudes2.append((cells[2]))
#longitudes2 = [w.replace(dms_dd(val) for w in longitudes]

ff.close()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: in your post, the values are separated by space, but in your code, they are separeted by comma. Which one is correct?

Answer (score 2):

First, write a function that converts one line of input, then loop over the input lines:

```
import csv
filename = r'C:\workspace\code\hl.csv'
filename_decimal = r'C:\workspace\code\hundlich4.csv'

def dms_dd(degrees, minutes=0, seconds=0):
    if degrees >= 0:
        decimal = degrees + minutes/60.0 + seconds/3600.0
    else:
        decimal = degrees - minutes/60.0 - seconds/3600.0
    return decimal

def convert_line(data):
    return data[0], dms_dd(*map(float,data[1].split())), dms_dd(*map(float, data[2].split()))

with open(filename) as inf:
    reader = csv.reader(inf)
    with open(filename_decimal) as outf:
        writer = csv.writer(outf)
        writer.write(next(reader)) # header
        for line in reader:
            writer.write(convert_line(line))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function [`clean_lat_long()`](https://docs.dataprep.ai/user_guide/clean/clean_lat_long.html) from the library [DataPrep](https://dataprep.ai/) if you load the csv file into a pandas DataFrame. Install DataPrep with `pip install dataprep`.

```py
from dataprep.clean import clean_lat_long
df = pd.DataFrame({"latitude": ["46°57'01''N", "1°23'39.29''S"],
     "longitude": ["101°26'46.29''E", "101°35'30.45''E"]})

df2 = clean_lat_long(df, lat_col="latitude", long_col="longitude", split=True)
# print(df2)
        latitude        longitude  latitude_clean  longitude_clean
0    46°57'01''N  101°26'46.29''E         46.9503         101.4462
1  1°23'39.29''S  101°35'30.45''E         -1.3942         101.5918
```